# Position sticky and overflow scroll restrictions?

Tags: css, overflow, css-position

Are there any restrictions on overflow scroll or position sticky? I created demo, if you scroll to the far left (so all cards are stacked) and than look at far right card. All OK. But if i change left value of far right card to lets say 1400px or something like that, the card wont move to right. Same way i tested this, i added 1400px to the penultimate card, the card will move just for how many space it has till reaches the left side of wrapper border. But if you scroll back, all items will go beyond this right border of wrapper. 
Demo (This code does not work well in this editor):

```css
:root {
    --left: 60px;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 1442px;
    border-right: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
    display: flex;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.wrapper, .box1, .box2, .box3, .box4, .box5, .box6, .box7, .box8 {
    position: sticky;
    height: 750px;
} 

.box1 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    left: calc(var(--left) * 0);
}
.box2 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background-color: #333;
    left: calc(var(--left) * 1);
}
.box3 {
    min-width: 702px;
    background-color: #4d4d4d;
    left: calc(var(--left) * 2);
}
.box4 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #666;
    left: calc(var(--left) * 3);
}
.box5 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #808080;
    left: calc(var(--left) * 4);
}
.box6 {
    min-width: 357px;
    background-color: #999;
    left: calc(var(--left) * 5);
}
.box7 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #b3b3b3;
    left: calc(var(--left) * 6);
}
.box8 {
    min-width: 630px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    left: calc(var(--left) * 7);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box3"></div>
  <div class="box4"></div>
  <div class="box5"></div>
  <div class="box6"></div>
  <div class="box7"></div>
  <div class="box8"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Anyone? Please?